# ConfigParser and String interpolation with env variable

Tags: python, configparser

it's a little bit I'm out of python syntax and I have a problem in reading a `.ini` file with interpolated values.

this is my ini file:

```
[DEFAULT]
home=$HOME
test_home=$home

[test]
test_1=$test_home/foo.csv
test_2=$test_home/bar.csv
```

Those lines

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('config.ini')

print parser.get('test', 'test_1')
```

does output

```
$test_home/foo.csv
```

while I'm expecting

```
/Users/nkint/foo.csv
```

#### EDIT:

I supposed that the `$` syntax was implicitly included in the so called **string interpolation** (referring to the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)):

> On top of the core functionality, SafeConfigParser supports
>   interpolation. This means values can contain format strings which
>   refer to other values in the same section, or values in a special
>   DEFAULT section.

But I'm wrong. How to handle this case?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First of all according to the documentation you should use `%(test_home)s` to interpolate `test_home`. Moreover the key are case insensitive and you can't use both `HOME` and `home` keys. Finally you can use `SafeConfigParser(os.environ)` to take in account of you environment.

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
import os


parser = SafeConfigParser(os.environ)
parser.read('config.ini')
```

Where `config.ini` is

```
[DEFAULT]
test_home=%(HOME)s

[test]
test_1=%(test_home)s/foo.csv
test_2=%(test_home)s/bar.csv
```

Comment: I can't modify the ini syntax because other software already use it and it is with the `$` syntax

Comment: You should preprocess the file before use SafeConfigParse(). But you can just replace `$` syntax by `%()s` syntax. the real problem will be `home=$(HOME)` that become recursive. You could assume that the capital words came from environ and replace by something like __ENV__KEY after change the `sys.environ` dict too. I can't do it now... but you can tray by yourself

Comment: The one thing that got me about this implementation is if there are '%' marks in environment variables themselves, then the parser will throw an error. I had to write a function that would filter out those keys/values. Otherwise, I like this impl.

Comment: If you are working with other kinds of variables along with path variable, then use ConfigParser instead of SafeConfigParser else it will give an error %%' must be followed by '%%' or '(', found: %r" % (rest,))

Comment: home=${HOME} is the proper way to interpolate the environment variable

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer, but was concerned how it casually imports all environment variables instead of just the relevant ones, so I passed on only the desired subset to `ConfigParser`: `{k: v for k, v in os.environ.items() if k in ('MY_ENV_1', 'MY_ENV_2')}`.

Comment: It should be noted that `SafeConfigParser` only exists in python 2. It is replaced by `ConfigParser` in python 3.

Answer (score 13):

You can write custom interpolation in case of Python 3:

```py
import configparser
import os


class EnvInterpolation(configparser.BasicInterpolation):
    """Interpolation which expands environment variables in values."""

    def before_get(self, parser, section, option, value, defaults):
        value = super().before_get(parser, section, option, value, defaults)
        return os.path.expandvars(value)


cfg = """
[section1]
key = value
my_path = $PATH
"""

config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=EnvInterpolation())
config.read_string(cfg)
print(config['section1']['my_path'])
```

Comment: Hey @Alex, I want to fetch Environment variables and values from other sections also. How can I do this? Extended Interpolation doesn't look straight forward.

Comment: please add missing call to `super().before_get(...)`

Comment: @srand9, I have fixed the example, now you can use %-notation to reference values from other sections of the same config. See, [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/configparser.html#configparser.BasicInterpolation) for more details

Comment: I've kind of jeopardized your answer to post my own answer addressing @srand9 concern (which is mine too). I hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to expand some environment variables, you can do so using `os.path.expandvars` before parsing a `StringIO` stream:

```
import ConfigParser
import os
import StringIO

with open('config.ini', 'r') as cfg_file:
    cfg_txt = os.path.expandvars(cfg_file.read())

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(StringIO.StringIO(cfg_txt))
```

Answer (score 3):

the trick for proper variable substitution from environment is to use the ${} syntax for the environment variables:

```
[DEFAULT]
test_home=${HOME}

[test]
test_1=%(test_home)s/foo.csv
test_2=%(test_home)s/bar.csv
```

Comment: In this case you are forced to use the basic ConfigParser interpolation, right?

Answer (score 3):

Based on @alex-markov answer (and code) and @srand9 comment, the following solution works with environment variables and cross-section references.

Note that the interpolation is now based on `ExtendedInterpolation` to allow cross-sections references and on `before_read` instead of `before_get`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import configparser
import os


class EnvInterpolation(configparser.ExtendedInterpolation):
    """Interpolation which expands environment variables in values."""

    def before_read(self, parser, section, option, value):
        value = super().before_read(parser, section, option, value)
        return os.path.expandvars(value)


cfg = """
[paths]
foo : ${HOME}
[section1]
key = value
my_path = ${paths:foo}/path
"""

config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=EnvInterpolation())
config.read_string(cfg)
print(config['section1']['my_path'])
```

Comment: This works until you need to iterate over multiple items in a section, for k, v in config.items() it iterates and returns every environment variable set instead of the values in the ini

Answer (score 2):

[ConfigParser.get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.ConfigParser.get) values are strings, even if you set values as integer or True. But ConfigParser has [getint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.getint), [getfloat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.getfloat) and [getboolean](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.ConfigParser.getboolean).

**settings.ini**

```
[default]
home=/home/user/app
tmp=%(home)s/tmp
log=%(home)s/log
sleep=10
debug=True
```

**config reader**

```
>>> from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
>>> parser = SafeConfigParser()
>>> parser.read('/home/user/app/settings.ini')
>>> parser.get('defaut', 'home')
'/home/user/app'
>>> parser.get('defaut', 'tmp')
'/home/user/app/tmp'
>>> parser.getint('defaut', 'sleep')
10
>>> parser.getboolean('defaut', 'debug')
True
```

**Edit**

Indeed you could get name values as environ var if you initialize `SafeConfigParser` with `os.environ`. Thanks for the [Michele's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26588269/841339) answer.

Comment: I can't modify the ini syntax because other software already use it and it is with the $ syntax

Answer (score 2):

Below is a simple solution that

- Can use default value if no environment variable is provided
- Overrides variables with environment variables (if found)
- needs no custom interpolation implementation

Example:
`my_config.ini`

```ini
[DEFAULT]
HOST=http://www.example.com
CONTEXT=${HOST}/auth/
token_url=${CONTEXT}/oauth2/token
```

ConfigParser:

```py
import os
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation())
ini_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'my_config.ini')
    
# replace variables with environment variables(if exists) before loading ini file
with open(ini_file, 'r') as cfg_file:
    cfg_env_txt = os.path.expandvars(cfg_file.read())

config.read_string(cfg_env_txt)

print(config['DEFAULT']['token_url'])
```

Output:

- If no environtment variable `$HOST` or `$CONTEXT` is present this config will take the default value
- user can override the default value by creating `$HOST`, `$CONTEXT` environment variable
- works well with docker container

Answer (score 1):

Quite late, but maybe it can help someone else looking for the same answers that I had recently. Also, one of the comments was how to fetch Environment variables and values from other sections. Here is how I deal with both converting environment variables and multi-section tags when reading in from an INI file.

INI FILE:

```
[PKG]
# <VARIABLE_NAME>=<VAR/PATH>
PKG_TAG = Q1_RC1

[DELIVERY_DIRS]
# <DIR_VARIABLE>=<PATH>
NEW_DELIVERY_DIR=${DEL_PATH}\ProjectName_${PKG:PKG_TAG}_DELIVERY
```

Python Class that uses the ExtendedInterpolation so that you can use the `${PKG:PKG_TAG}` type formatting. I add the ability to convert the windows environment vars when I read in INI to a string using the builtin `os.path.expandvars()` function such as `${DEL_PATH}` above.

```
import os
from configparser import ConfigParser, ExtendedInterpolation

class ConfigParser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """
        initialize the file parser with
        ExtendedInterpolation to use ${Section:option} format
        [Section]
        option=variable
        """
        self.config_parser = ConfigParser(interpolation=ExtendedInterpolation())

    def read_ini_file(self, file='./config.ini'):
        """
        Parses in the passed in INI file and converts any Windows environ vars.

        :param file: INI file to parse
        :return: void
        """
        # Expands Windows environment variable paths
        with open(file, 'r') as cfg_file:
            cfg_txt = os.path.expandvars(cfg_file.read())

        # Parses the expanded config string
        self.config_parser.read_string(cfg_txt)

    def get_config_items_by_section(self, section):
        """
        Retrieves the configurations for a particular section

        :param section: INI file section
        :return: a list of name, value pairs for the options in the section
        """
        return self.config_parser.items(section)

    def get_config_val(self, section, option):
        """
        Get an option value for the named section.

        :param section: INI section
        :param option: option tag for desired value
        :return: Value of option tag
        """
        return self.config_parser.get(section, option)

    @staticmethod
    def get_date():
        """
        Sets up a date formatted string.

        :return: Date string
        """
        return datetime.now().strftime("%Y%b%d")

    def prepend_date_to_var(self, sect, option):
        """
        Function that allows the ability to prepend a
        date to a section variable.

        :param sect: INI section to look for variable
        :param option: INI search variable under INI section
        :return: Void - Date is prepended to variable string in INI
        """
        if self.config_parser.get(sect, option):
            var = self.config_parser.get(sect, option)
            var_with_date = var + '_' + self.get_date()
            self.config_parser.set(sect, option, var_with_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems in the last version `3.5.0`, ConfigParser was not reading the env variables, so I end up providing a custom Interpolation based on the `BasicInterpolation` one.

```
class EnvInterpolation(BasicInterpolation):
    """Interpolation as implemented in the classic ConfigParser,
    plus it checks if the variable is provided as an environment one in uppercase.
    """

    def _interpolate_some(self, parser, option, accum, rest, section, map,
                          depth):
        rawval = parser.get(section, option, raw=True, fallback=rest)
        if depth > MAX_INTERPOLATION_DEPTH:
            raise InterpolationDepthError(option, section, rawval)
        while rest:
            p = rest.find("%")
            if p < 0:
                accum.append(rest)
                return
            if p > 0:
                accum.append(rest[:p])
                rest = rest[p:]
            # p is no longer used
            c = rest[1:2]
            if c == "%":
                accum.append("%")
                rest = rest[2:]
            elif c == "(":
                m = self._KEYCRE.match(rest)
                if m is None:
                    raise InterpolationSyntaxError(option, section,
                                                   "bad interpolation variable reference %r" % rest)
                var = parser.optionxform(m.group(1))
                rest = rest[m.end():]
                try:
                    v = os.environ.get(var.upper())
                    if v is None:
                        v = map[var]
                except KeyError:
                    raise InterpolationMissingOptionError(option, section, rawval, var) from None
                if "%" in v:
                    self._interpolate_some(parser, option, accum, v,
                                           section, map, depth + 1)
                else:
                    accum.append(v)
            else:
                raise InterpolationSyntaxError(
                    option, section,
                    "'%%' must be followed by '%%' or '(', "
                    "found: %r" % (rest,))
```

The difference between the `BasicInterpolation` and the `EnvInterpolation` is in:

```
   v = os.environ.get(var.upper())
   if v is None:
       v = map[var]
```

where I'm trying to find the `var` in the enviornment before checking in the `map`.