# Python Config Parser environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables, configparser

I am trying to read some environment variables into my ConfigParser file.

I was referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586801/configparser-and-string-interpolation-with-env-variable) but I am getting

```
"InterpolationDepthError: Value interpolation too deeply recursive" error.
section: [amazon]
    option : amazon_access_key
    rawval : %(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY)s
```

Here is the portion of my config file:

```
[amazon]
amazon_access_key=%(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY)s
amazon_secret_key=%(AMAZON_SECRET_KEY)s
```

And this is what I am writing to call the file:

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
import os

config = SafeConfigParser(os.environ)
config.read('config.txt')
```

When I am calling these variables directly in the "amazon" section, I get the above stated error.

When I call these variables in the "default" section, like:

```
[default]
aws_access_key=%(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY)s
aws_secret_key=%(AMAZON_SECRET_KEY)s

[amazon]
    amazon_access_key=%(aws_access_key)s
    amazon_secret_key=%(aws_secret_key)s
```

I get the following error:

```
ConfigParser.InterpolationMissingOptionError: Bad value substitution:
    section: [amazon]
    option : amazon_access_key
    key    : aws_access_key
    rawval : %(aws_access_key)s
```

What am I missing here?

Also, how can I have separate config files for local and production deployments? Currently, all the configurations are same for local and production environments.

Comment: have you tried using environment variable names that don't shadow the original key? Also you might want to see whether the tabs underneath `[amazon]` section matter.

Comment: There are no tabs under the [amazon] section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
import ConfigParser
import os
class CaseConfigParser(SafeConfigParser):
     def optionxform(self, optionstr):
         return optionstr
config = CaseConfigParser(os.environ)
config.read('config.ini')
print config.get('amazon', 'amazon_access_key')
```

Explanation:
The problem here is with optionxform, which turns all options to lower case by default. eventually, it will have key and value equal, similar to following.

```
[amazon]
amazon_access_key=%(amazon_access_key)s
```

Another solution can be - change names of keys in config.txt NOT equal to env vars.

```
[amazon]
aak=%(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY)s
```

and then

```
config = SafeConfigParser(os.environ)
config.read('config.ini')
print config.get('amazon', 'aak')
```

Comment: So, If I change the name of the key, will this still work? In that case, I won't have to create another class. I want to avoid this because I have to call this config file in multiple other files.

Comment: Probably a monkey patch `SafeConfigParser.optionxform = lambda self, st: st `

Comment: I have accepted this answer but since I have less reputation, it isn't showing in the count.

Answer (score -2):

You should remember that the default section should be capitalised.

```
[DEFAULT]
```

Making this change should solve the problem.

Comment: changing to [DEFAULT] didn't help. I am still getting InterpolationMissingOptionError