# Python ConfigParser .ini parsing and portable variable substitutions

Tags: python, pipenv, mypy, python-config

I want to have a `.ini` entry that references special variables
e.g.

```
[magic_module]
magic_directory: ${env:PWD}/magic
```

currently, I have the non-portable

```
[magic_module]
magic_directory: C:/Users/user1/projects/project1/magic
```

I would like to have a `.ini` path entry that is more portable instead of hard-coded to my computer.  Does the Python `ConfigParser` natively perform substitutions like this?

---

This is slightly different than SO question [ConfigParser and String interpolation with env variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586801/configparser-and-string-interpolation-with-env-variable) because I am wondering about *any* possible default interpolated variables, not just environment variables.

This is for passing information to a different module (`mypy`) that uses `ConfigParser`.

Specifically, this is for improving portability in a Python package.  I'm trying to set the [`mypy_path` within a `mypy.ini`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html#config-file-import-discovery-global) while working with a pipenv-created virtualenv python environment. The user install module paths will change so I want to portably set that for `mypy`.

Using Python 3.7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConfigParser and String interpolation with env variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586801/configparser-and-string-interpolation-with-env-variable)

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstand something in my experience I found that:  a) `.env`-files + `pipenv run` + `os.environ` or b) `.env`-files + [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) solves all my needs. Both solutions are quite portable. Do I miss something?